# Создать SOAP сервис

Tags: soap, grails

Мне нужно создать SOAP сервис. Я использую grails 3.2. Это одно из [официальных решений](http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/guide/webServices.html#SOAP). Я хотел бы использовать [cxf plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/cxf), но я получаю ошибку на этапе загрузки расширения:

> [Fatal Error] cxf-3.1.1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project
>   'testGrails12'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
>   ':runtime'. Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.1.1. Required
>   by: testgrails12:testGrails12:0.1 Could not resolve
>   org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.1.1. Could not parse POM https
>   ://repo.grails.
>   org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cxf/3.1.1/cxf-3.1.1.pom Content is
>   not allowed in prolog. CONFIGURE FAILED * Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output. Total time: 19.337 secs
>   Error | Error initializing classpath: Content is not allowed in
>   prolog. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Я попытался использовать этот плагин (http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/cxf-client) Файлы скачиваются, но приложения не запускаются :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'. A problem
>   occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe'' Try: Run with --stacktrace
>   option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
>   get more log output. Error | Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace
>   to see the full trace) Process finished with exit code 1

Мне нужно создать soap сервис. Рассмотрю различные варианты.

bild.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.11.6"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.7"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "testgrails12"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:cookie:2.0.5'
  //  compile "org.grails.plugins:cxf-client:2.1.2"
  //  compile 'org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.1.1'
  //  compile 'org.grails.plugins:cxf-client:3.0.7'
    //compile 'com.nayidisha.grails.uploadr:grails3-uploadr:3.1.0'
   // compile "org.grails.plugins:ajax-uploader:1.1"
/*    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2:1.+'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-google:1.1.+'*/
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.6"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40'
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Comment: добавьте ваш build.gradle в вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил